# how can i get the href tag in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup of python

```
<div class="test1">
   <a href="www.google.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test2">
   <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test3">
   <a href="www.msn.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test4">
   <a href="www.naver.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test5">
   <a href="www.ios.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>
```

like this situation, i wanna get a specific href info. For example how can i use the class name, when i need a href='www.ios.com'.

HTML file has more than 1000 'a' selector and included url address is dynamic.

how can i get this? please answer me T.T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full working example.

For example you can use `select` and CSS selectors like `.class`, `#id` and `tag`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content='''<div class="test1">
   <a href="www.google.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test2">
   <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test3">
   <a href="www.msn.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test4">
   <a href="www.naver.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>

<div class="test5">
   <a href="www.ios.com" blur blur~> text </a>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

all_a = soup.select('.test5 a')

for a in all_a:
    print(a['href'])

# www.ios.com
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: thank you for your comment. But i want to get an address that doesn't have a  class name or id name. And it is included in another div or span. In this situation like my example, how can i get specific address ;

Comment: this example doesn't use `id` or `class` and it get `href` - where is the problem ? did you try it ? this example use your HTML and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But In my case, the number of every 'a' selector is more than 1000. If i use your way, i can't distinguish what i need. And i also know about basic instruction of beautifulsoup.

Comment: you didn't mention about 1000 selectors in question - and I can't read in your mind. My example answers for your current question. If you need something more then create new question with more information.

Comment: I'm afraid of my mistake T.T. Edit my question if you have time please solve my problem!

Comment: Is there a way to get the 'href' within the select method itself and avoid the additional for loop?

Comment: @MasayoMusic as I know you can't do this in `BeautifulSoup` and you have to use `for`-loop or list comprehension `all_href = [ a['href'] for a in all_a ]`.  You could do this with mdoule `lxml` and `xpath` - `all_href = html.xpath('//div[@class="test5"]/a/@href')`. Or in `Scrapy` you could use `css(('.test5 a::attr(href)')` because it convert it to `xpath`

Answer (score 0):

for item in results
  a = item.find("a")
  item_href = a['href']
  print(item_href)